# Google Analytics Cross Device Tracking Config

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, web-analytics, universal-analytics

Ok so with Universal Analytics out of beta I wanted to drop this question:

What is the best account, property and/or view set up to take advantage of cross device tracking? Explanation in the recent post on the GA blog:

http://analytics.blogspot.com/2014/04/universal-analytics-out-of-beta-into.html

I am aware that I have several options all explained here:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587087

However its not very clear as to which of those options is best to properly track sessions/users across devices. For example my big question is...do I really have to use the same GA code on all my apps to take advantage of this?

Or do I only have to create a property within the same account?

Any and all help would be most appreciated to myself and many others getting into UA.

Comment: When you say all my apps does it mean you have different website and different mobile applications?

Comment: Yes mobile apps (ios, android, etc.) as well as mobile and desktop website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need add it in the 2 sites. But you need create a [property](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042508) 
[Reference](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1PvVFwsGLD6j5GQ_WDL2YGqPnV8SizkTQD6d0tZCkwgw/edit?pli=1#slide=id.gc26bc6a7_50) and [Implement a Universal Analytics tracking code](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080)

Comment: This is definitely the best answer...thank you! The link is great!However I am not clear on what you are saying about needing to add it "in the 2 sites"? Are you saying the same GA ID should be used across all apps? Really??

Comment: Yeah I looked everywhere in the links you provided and I see nothing that mentions the proper usage of the tid (Google Analytics ID eg XXXXX-3).

Comment: I was hoping and would think that it would work with all properties under a single account. So xxxxx-1, xxxxx-2 and xxxxx-3 would all benefit from cross device tracking in Universal Analytics. However I am not sure...sounds like I could be wrong (probably) but just want a 100% confirmation.

Comment: Works only configuring the preferences, if you like, share your url sites and we can test. PS. Give me the check if my answers is the best :) -

Comment: I cannot share my URL....not sure what you would test either. Not sure what you mean when you say "Works only in configuring the preferences"? I am confused...all I need to know is if I need to use the exact ID on all apps or not?

Comment: This is a good question. You can add it as a new question and I can help you with that. Mark this question with a check if was usable for you.

Comment: I would love to just keep it on this question for everyone. Can you just answer here?

Comment: Is important create a new question. People search answers about specific questions. Create a new thread to help all the comunity and the new users to find answers.

Comment: I can't say that I agree. This question was intended to get the full answer on how to best configure a Universal Analytics account to take advantage of cross device tracking. I don't understand why we would need to threads/questions to accomplish this. I feel that doing so would go against what Stackoverflow considers an optimal user experience. I initially asked the same question in my original question: "For example my big question is...do I really have to use the same GA code on all my apps to take advantage of this?"